# Is there a way of displaying the Yandex panorama coverage layer on a normal Yandex map?

Tags: yandex-maps, yandex-api

I'm making a two panel web app with a map and panorama with Yandex Maps API and I need to toggle the panorama coverage layer on the map.

Are there ways of showing and removing the panorama coverage layer without using the default map type drop down menu on Yandex Maps API?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of showing and removing the panorama coverage layer without using the default map type drop-down menu on Yandex Maps API.